# Do we need a [CS193P] tag on SO?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, clean-up

While cleaning up some [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) questions, I came across the [cs193p](/questions/tagged/cs193p) tag. It seems to be related to an iOS programming course offered at Stanford University.  The videos and course materials seem to be available online, causing students to use the tag to identify their programming efforts related to this class. Currently 81 questions have the tag.

I would assume that this tag is equally unnecessary as the [homework](/questions/tagged/homework) tag and might proceed cleaning them up and giving the questions some needed attention. Any thoughts on this before I proceed? Is there any need to keep the tag around?

Comment: ...I first parsed that as [SCP-193](http://scp-wiki.wikidot.com/scp-193) and was wondering if I really was on Meta-SO...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That tag is a lot more specific than [homework](/questions/tagged/homework).  You can at least be sure that all the [cs193p](/questions/tagged/cs193p) questions are going to be related, and it seems that some people might be using it as a filter/search to find those related questions.  I'd argue that the [cs193p](/questions/tagged/cs193p) tag has roughly the same utility and purpose as [sicp](/questions/tagged/sicp) and [clrs](/questions/tagged/clrs).

**Addendum:** I do want to add that that tag will only remain useful for as long as the course material stays online and is available to everyone.  If that goes away, most of the questions are probably going to be pointless.

Comment: And [project-euler] come to think of it.... Is "it serves as a search filter" enough though?

Comment: @Bart Good question.  I'm tempted to say it is, since all we really have to go on is what's in the [Tags](http://stackoverflow.com/tags) page (i.e., there's nothing in the FAQ).  "A tag is a keyword or label that categorizes your question with other, similar questions. Using the right tags makes it easier for others to find and answer your question."  It does fit that description (a lot better than `homework`), so unless we have some other Meta precedent, I'd let it stay.

Comment: Hmm, that seems fair enough. I'll leave the tag in place then. Though it seems to be an excellent filter to find questions which need some clean-up anyway. :)

Answer (score 2):

There is currently [one user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1178420/aleene) who is probably using the tag specifically to find questions to answer: He's asked no questions, and all 9 answers are in the [cs193p](/questions/tagged/cs193p) tag.

Sure it's just one person, but to me that seems sufficient to justify the tag.

Comment: I McCannot believe you just said that. Well, I can, and it's a valid point, but I just had to use your name in a sentence. I'm immature like that.

Answer (score -1):

## Burninate the tag!

Especially if it yields questions like https://stackoverflow.com/q/12719329/561731

They are of no use to the Stack Overflow system.

[image]

Comment: +1 for your input. Given the discussions above I have decided to hold off on this for now. It seems people find enough value in the tag for it to remain. I'm not entirely decided yet, but perhaps I'll come back to it later.